# Climate Change - finding solutions

Tags: climate-change

My questions are: is there a significant, joint, worldwide, inter-disciplinary, scientific effort to study (brainstorm) possible solutions to climate-change?

If it does exist, in whatever form, does it really include many if not all disciplines, beyond natural sciences and engineering? Additionally, do economists regularly talk to experts in game-theory, sociologists to mathematicians, chemists to ... and everyone else?

It seems to me that today any such work is quite fragmented, left to smaller groups, at universities for example. And it is clearly not found under the umbrella of the IPCC, the UNFCCC, or the COPs (unless I am missing something - which could be your answer).

One might think that such an effort would require significant funding, and that the lack of such is to be seen as a political decision. But neither am I interested in the underlying politics, nor in more COP like conferences. This question is really and only about: where is 'finding solutions' (brainstorming) done, who does it, where, exactly how? How big is it? Is the scale adequate to the scale of the problem  (think Apollo!). If the answer is 'no', I would also like to get some feedback on 'why not'?

This question is related to my earlier question on the same subject, which appeared to be only borderline on-topic to this forum.

Comment: the solutions is known we need to stop burning stuff and to remove carbon from the system.

Comment: energy/transportation sectors need to change to renewables.  In many successful models that includes a combination of battery and hyrdogen technology, which both exist.  Asking big oil and king coal to step down can be fatal, though.  Carbon sequestration only works if you stop emitting billions of tons of carbon every year.

Comment: I agree that the best route would be 'reduction', but this should not stop us from looking elsewhere because we know how difficult this is going to be. Once more, I am not asking for a personal opinion on what solutions might work, what policy change to request. I want to know who thinks about solutions 'not obvious'. if Please read my question again and take it serious.

Comment: i think this question is a better fit here https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/ your question is more about how to solve the problem and less about earth science.

Comment: Would somebody please explain to me what's going on and why exactly ? Moderation is fine, but I do read and conform to the published rules. WHAT are you worried about ??? (and no, moving it to sustainability.SE does not make a lot of sense).

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the IPCC. https://www.ipcc.ch/ Working group 2 (adaptation) and Working group 3 (mitigation)

Comment: @Juergen I'm not sure if your question would fit on [sustainability.SE], perhaps it would fit on [Politics.SE], perhaps even on [Academia.SE], perhaps nowhere, but wherever it may or may not fit: as you phrased it, is very broad and not very clear.  On Stack Exchange, we're looking for focussed questions that can be reasonably answered within several paragraphs + figures, as opposed to a multi-page article or a short book.  You write "it's clearly not found under IPCC", but if that isn't what you're looking for, then I don't know what you're asking anymore.

Comment: I give up on this, it's not so important. Assuming that we share a science background, I wonder about commensurability. I am simply asking 'who is doing X ?' with X being well explained. It is hard to imagine that this ain't clear or that the answer cannot fit in ONE line. No, I think you read more into this than there is (like 'what does this mean ?', or 'who will it make look bad ?' or 'why on "our" board ?' It is a simple question, with a simple answer and there is no better place than right here to read it to involved people. If you worry for bad responses block them, not the question.